# How to iterate over all the nodes from a content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to recover some info from a field of all the nodes of a specific content type.
I know how to do it using a `db_query` and getting all the node ID then iterate over them.
What I would like to know is if there's is another way around this using drupal functions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can query that information directly through [`node_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7)

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'my_type'));
```

You can add as many property conditions to the `$conditions` array (second argument) as you like, so status, created, etc are fair game too.

`$conditions` is technically deprecated (I imagine in favour of `EntityFieldQuery`) but the chances of that functionality ever being removed from Drupal 7 are basically none. It would break too much.

Comment: It is gone in Drupal 8, though.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it's exactly what I was looking for, but will use @MPD solution because it will also work with Drupal 8 :)

Comment: @drcelus Yes MPD's method is definitely the best way to go, I probably should have mentioned that - `EntityFieldQuery` all the way :) I put this is in more for posterity than anything else

Comment: `entity_load_multiple` exists in D8. You can't load by properties though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I did mean that $conditions is gone from D8.

Answer (score 37):

Drupal core provides a class called [`EntityFieldQuery()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).  There is also a [handy document page](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) for using it, that has lots of examples.  In its simplest form:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'page')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // do something awesome
  }
}
```

This will load all published nodes of type "page". You periodically need to adjust this to

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'page')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);

 foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE);
    // do something awesome
  }
}
```

to avoid loading too much at once, which can cause memory issues.